# Ninject MVC3 & Web Forms. Am I doing this right?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I have a new MVC3 application with a few legacy Web Form pages. I'm familiar with with Ninject and MVC but I want to use Ninject with the Web Form pages as well. I've hacked something together but I'm not sure if it's the right way to go about this.

I've exposed the Ninject kernel as follows:

```
public static IKernel Kernel { get { return CreateKernel(); } }

private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    RegisterServices(kernel);
    return kernel;
}
```

I then created a base class for my Web Form pages that injects the kernel:

```
public class NinjectBase : Page
{
    public IKernel Kernel { get; private set; }
    public NinjectBase() { Kernel = NinjectMVC3.Kernel; } 
    public void Page_Init() { Kernel.Inject(this); }
}
```

This seems to work well enough. Is there anything wrong with this approach? Is there another way I should be going about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ninject 2.4 will support all the web technologies (ASP.NET, MVC, WCF) side a side.

If you are not yet on production go and get 2.3.0.x

- the source from Github: https://github.com/ninject
- or binaries from the Continuous Integration Server at http://teamcity.codebetter.com

You will need Ninject, Ninject.Web, Ninject.Web.Common, Nnject.Web.MVC3